# If $A$,$B$ are rings then $A\times B$ is a ring

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> A collection $\Omega$ calls ring if $\forall A,B\in \Omega$ then $A\cup B$, $A\cap B$ and $A-B \in \Omega$.

**Problem**
Give an example where $\Omega_{1}, \Omega_{2}$ are rings but $\Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}$ is not a ring; where $G_{1} \in \Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}$ is written $G_{1}=A_{1}\times B_{1}$ where $A_{1} \in \Omega_{1}$ and $B_{1} \in \Omega_{2}$, similarly for $G_{2}$

What I tried is use simple examples using a collection with numbers where fails $G_{1}-G_{2}$. The last thing I tried is $\Omega_{1}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}\}$, $\Omega_{2}=\{\emptyset, \mathbb{N}, \mathbb{Z}-\{0\}, \mathbb{Z}^{-}-\{0\}\}$, where $\mathbb{Z}^{-}$ denotes the negatives integers.

$\Omega_{1},\Omega_{2}$ are rings but if I took, for example $G_{1}=\mathbb{N}\times(\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})$ and $G_{2}=\mathbb{N}\times(\mathbb{Z}^{-}-\{0\})$, but $G_{1}-G_{2}=[\mathbb{N}\times(\mathbb{Z}-\{0\})]-[\mathbb{N}\times(\mathbb{Z}^{-}-\{0\})]=\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N} \in \Omega_{1}\times\Omega_{2}$

So I don't know what example works, could you help me?, please.

Comment: By  $\Omega_1X\Omega_2$ do you mean $\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$?

Comment: There I used `\times`.

Comment: We always have $$(A \times B) - (A \times C) = A \times (B-C) \\ (A \times B) \cup (A \times C) = A \times (B\cup C) \\ (A \times B) \cap (A \times C) = A \times (B\cap C)$$ so if you want to find a counterexample, you cannot set the first "coordinate" (for the lack of a better word) equal.

Answer (score 2):

Take $\Omega_1=\Omega_2=2^{\{0,1\}}$. Then $\{0\}\times\{0,1\}=\{(0,0),(0,1)\}\in\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ and $\{0,1\}\times\{0\}=\{(0,0),(1,0)\}\in\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$ but their union $\{(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)\}\not\in\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$